# How to grab only a certain row of a two-dimensional matrix in java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

When I have a two-dimensional matrix in java, but I only want to work with a certain row of that matrix respectively creating a new array that contains the contents of the matrix in that certain row, how would I accomplish that (with primitives)?

So, for example, we would write:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];
```

Now we have a two-dimensional matrix with 10 rows and 10 columns. Assume that we fill the whole matrix with certain elements, and now, I wish to work only with the first row, meaning to define a new array that contains exactly the elements of the first row of the matrix.

Comment: Show us your code, an example matrix, what are you trying to "grab" and what do you actually grab (expected vs. actual).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that row means the horizontal segments of the matrix (as it almost always is):

In a 2 dimensional array in java, the rows are the first index and the columns are the second index.
Basically a two dimensional array is an array of arrays. So

```
int[][] intArray = new int[10][3];
```

is actually an array of size 10. Each element in the array is **an array in itself** of size 3.

Say you have an array of integers

```
int[][] integerArray; //we have to initialize the array.
```

then we want to work with the 1st row. We would use:

```
int[] arr = integerArray[0];
```

**LIMITATIONS**

1. The matrix must be initialized (must have values in cells)
2. The matrix must have a 1st row

Note: we use `integerArray[0]` because arrays start at index 0, so the third row would be `integerArray[2]`

Comment: Thanks! What happens with the column in your second line? Why can it just be "ignored"?

Comment: in java a multidimensional array is just an array of arrays.

Comment: @Julian But you should edit your question to explain what you mean better. It's good practice. Also, if you accept the answer, mark it as accepted (V symbol under answer score)

Comment: And how do you know if that's what the OP refers to as "row" and not "column" ? :)

Comment: @alfasin I assume. It's a valid assumption

Comment: I gave some more details, is that enough? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I am a mathematician, we normally refer to it as "row", didn't know that this might be confusing.

Comment: @Julian perfect

Comment: @Julian also mathematician, it's the same in programming and in math in this case.

Comment: @ItamarGreen whenever you have to assume anything in order to provide an answer, you should ask the OP for clarification. Grabbing the "row" like this is trivial, the other case is less so since it requires iterating the matrix.

Comment: @alfasin that is perfectly true, but in this case, the question (as it was in the first revision) was sufficiently clear (at least for me) to answer. Afterwards, when the answer was given, I wanted to make sure it answers almost exactly what OP wanted, so more clarification was in order, but not necessary.